# the_content() for a Wordpress Theme Doesn't Produce <p> Tags

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

For some reason, the theme I've made won't turn the double newlines (pressing enter in the Visual editor) into paragraph tags. I tried disabling all plugins and it still doesn't work. It does work if I change to a default theme though. Any ideas?

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <div class="container">
        <h2>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </h2>
      </div> <!-- /container -->
    <div class="container contentArea">

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's done by the `wpautop` function (see [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/formatting.php#L174)), which I thought was enabled by default (see [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L130)).

Perhaps you could add it manually to your theme?  Or better, work out why it's not being enabled.